# Caching values on a module level and unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Below is a module for querying and caching AWS STS tokens, the intention is to avoid querying STS if there is a valid token.

```
class Credentials:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sts_credentials = None
        self.token_expiry_time = None

    def is_token_expired(self):
        current_time_with_buffer = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2)
        return not self.token_expiry_time or self.token_expiry_time < current_time_with_buffer


CREDENTIALS_ = Credentials()


def get_credentials():
    if CREDENTIALS_.is_token_expired():
        sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
        LOGGER.info("The credentials are either empty or expiring, refreshing")
        try:
            sts_token = sts_client.assume_role(
                RoleArn=os.environ["KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE"],
                RoleSessionName=str(uuid.uuid4()))
        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(f"Error occurred while trying to assume role with {os.environ['KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE']}", e)
            raise e

        CREDENTIALS_.sts_credentials = {
            "aws_access_key_id": sts_token['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            "aws_secret_access_key": sts_token['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            "aws_session_token": sts_token['Credentials']['SessionToken']
        }

        CREDENTIALS_.token_expiry_time = sts_token["Credentials"]["Expiration"]

    return CREDENTIALS_.sts_credentials
```

One of the unit tests is as below, this passes in isolation, but fails when run alongside other tests, the reason being `CREDENTIALS_` variable, which is modified by other tests, I can set this value to `None`, but I want to know what is the cleaner way of clearing the cached value

```
def test_get_credentials_refreshes_token_if_about_to_expire(sts_response, credentials):

    with mock.patch("boto3.client") as mock_boto_client:
            mock_assume_role = mock_boto_client.return_value.assume_role
            mock_assume_role.return_value = sts_response

            get_credentials()
            actual_credentials = get_credentials()

            calls = [call('sts'),
                     call().assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/dummyarn', RoleSessionName=ANY),
                     call('sts'),
                     call().assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/dummyarn', RoleSessionName=ANY)]

            assert credentials == actual_credentials
            mock_boto_client.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner way would be to make sure that your `unit` tests are performing unit tests. This means that for every unit there should be no interaction with other units. Since you are using a global variable `CREDENTIALS_`, this is going to be nearly impossible.

### 1) easy fix

An easy fix would be to pass `CREDENTIALS_` as input argument. Then you can create a fake `CREDENTIALS_` object during each of the tests, that are tailored to your test conditions.

### 2) Better fix

A better solution would be, besides using the `credential` input argument, to break up the logic inside the `get_credentials`. By splitting it into smaller functions, you can separate the server logic and the credential updating. Making it easier to Mock and test. A possible division of the whole function would be:

- get_sts_token
- update_credentials
- get_credentials

Now the `get_sts_token` has connections to the server, but the `update_credentials` and `get_credentials` do not have to directly interact with it.

### Code

#### Example 1)

```
def update_credentials(credentials):
    if credentials.is_token_expired():
        sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
        LOGGER.info("The credentials are either empty or expiring, refreshing")
        try:
            sts_token = sts_client.assume_role(
                RoleArn=os.environ["KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE"],
                RoleSessionName=str(uuid.uuid4()))
        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(f"Error occurred while trying to assume role with {os.environ['KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE']}", e)
            raise e

        credentials.sts_credentials = {
            "aws_access_key_id": sts_token['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            "aws_secret_access_key": sts_token['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            "aws_session_token": sts_token['Credentials']['SessionToken']
        }

        credentials.token_expiry_time = sts_token["Credentials"]["Expiration"]

    return credentials


# Where you need the credentials
CREDENTIALS_ = update_credentials(CREDENTIALS_)
CREDENTIALS_.sts_credentials
```

Now you can insert your own `CREDENTIALS_` object in the test.

#### Example 2)

```
def get_sts_token():
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    LOGGER.info("The credentials are either empty or expiring, refreshing")
    try:
        sts_token = sts_client.assume_role(
                RoleArn=os.environ["KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE"],
                RoleSessionName=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(f"Error occurred while trying to assume role with {os.environ['KINESIS_ASSUME_ROLE']}", e)
        raise e
    return sts_token

def update_credentials(credentials, sts_token):
    credentials.sts_credentials = {
            "aws_access_key_id": sts_token['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            "aws_secret_access_key": sts_token['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            "aws_session_token": sts_token['Credentials']['SessionToken']
        }
    return credentials

def get_credentials(credentials: Credentials):
    if credentials.is_token_expired():
        sts_token = get_sts_token()
        credentials = update_credentials(credentials, sts_token)
    return credentials.sts_credentials
```

Comment: Example 2 looks much cleaner, but for two concerns
1. The abstraction is leaky now since the implementation details of managing token now are public functions
2. The state(credentials object) is now exposed to the public to be able to effectively use these functions.

Comment: you can coerce the credential updating inside the Credential class as an extremely private function (`__gets_sts_token`) or exclude those functions to the API by using the `__init__.py`. For the data being public. I am not sure if I get it, but it seems to me that  `CREDENTIALS_ ` is also publicly available and the credentials class is a storage for the retrieved (real) credentials. If you want to fully limit the user access to this, you can use a registration class, where you only allow the `get_credentials` method to be public.